# Resize QDockWidget objects with mouse

Tags: qt

How to resize QDockWidget objects with a mouse? There seems only 1px border to use a resize functionality. How to make this area larger?

Or may be it's a QMainWindow object property? which handle this qdocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the splitter/separator between the dock widget and whatever is on the other side.

You can set a style sheet on your mainwindow like the following:

```
QMainWindow::separator 
{ 
  height: 4px;
}
```

This tells the main window to make the separator 4 pixels instead of 1.
You can set the style sheet in the designer using the stylesheet editor, or you can pass it as a string using setStyleSheet(QString);

Hope this helps.